# How can i set the index to data.length?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can i set the (snapshot.data.documents.length = i) to get all the data and not just the first one?

```
                 .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return new Text('Connecting...');
                } else {
                  for(int i= 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length;) {
                    DocumentSnapshot test =
                    snapshot.data.documents[i];
                    print(test['GroupID']);
```

Comment: you forgot to increment i in for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code you might be getting first one because of the for loop

Your code shows this

> ```
>  for(int i= 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length;) {
>                     DocumentSnapshot test =
>                     snapshot.data.documents[i];
>                     print(test['GroupID']);
> ```

but it needs to be

> ```
>  for(int i= 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length;i++) {
>                 DocumentSnapshot test =
>                 snapshot.data.documents[i];
>                 print(test['GroupID']);
> ```

so that it can move through all documents

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to increment i in for loop.

```
 for(int i= 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length;i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to iterate inside a `StreamBuilder`, to access the data just do:

```
print(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["GroupID"]);
```

Example:

```
else {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                title:
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["GroupID"]),
                leading: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["groupName"])
              );
    });
}
```

use `listView` instead, and access all the data

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of a ```for-loop`` is like the one below:

```
for (initial_count_value; termination-condition; step) { 
   //statements 
}
```

But in your code, you forgot to increment the `for-loop`. This can be solved by addd `i++`. Check the code below:

```
 // add the increment statement 
 for(int i= 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
 // add your statement here
  }
``

I hope this helps.
```